# Is Varus any good in ranked games?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am considering getting this champion since he looks so awesome and snipes like a boss.

How good is Varus in ranked games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All champions got their pros and cons and like all others Varus got his counters.

In my opinion all champs who got skills to evade Varus skillshots will counter him hard like a bot lane with lot of cc.

So back to your question: if you're able to play passive and land Varus Q (which is his long range arrow skillshot) as often as possible you can definitely kick some other champs.

If you going to give it a try here is the link to the [Top-Rated Varus Guide](http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/build/varus-sorry-for-party-rocking-ad-carry-210898) available on [MobaFire](http://www.mobafire.com).
There you can find everything you need.